# Enabling and disabling word wrap automatically on different file extensions on Vim

Tags: vim, word-wrap, file-extension

I usually have to read .txt files with long lines, and at the same time edit some source file, and I like to see word wrap on the .txt files, and not in the ones that aren't.

Of course I can :set wrap and :set linebreak, but is there any way to make it automatucally, and dependent of the file extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess `:autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt set wrap` should do the trick

Answer (score 10):

There are two options that I can think of.  Firstly, you can use an autocmd as suggested by Tassos:

```
:au BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt set wrap
```

See:

```
:help autocmd
```

An alternative (that is probably more applicable if you've got multiple settings as you have suggested): create a file in the `after/ftplugin` directory of your vim configuration folder (see below) called `txt.vim` and it will be sourced whenever you open a `.txt` file.  You can put it in the plain `ftplugin` directory (rather than `after/ftplugin`), but it any built-in settings for `.txt` files will then not be loaded.

Put any commands you want in this file:

```
" This is txt.vim in the ftplugin directory
set wrap
set linebreak
```

See:

```
:help after-directory
:help ftplugin
```

**Vim Configuration Folder**

On Windows this would typically be something like:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\txt.vim
```

(I think), or

```
C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\txt.vim
```

or even:

```
C:\vim\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\txt.vim
```

On Linux, it is:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/txt.vim
```

For more info, see:

```
:help runtimepath
```

Comment: "set nowrap" to achieve the opposite also

Comment: For the ftplugin route, I also needed to add `au! BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt setf txt` to my `filetype.vim` file.

Comment: @sirlancelot I think it's counter indicated to modify filetype.vim. You should add that to your .vimrc instead.

Comment: I think the ftplugin file should use `setlocal` and not `set`, so that the settings aren't applied to all open buffers.

Answer (score 0):

you can do lot more with autocommand, refer here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/vi-and-vim-autocommand-3-steps-to-add-custom-header-to-your-file/