# How to enable line wrap only for certain filetypes in Vim?

Tags: vim, word-wrap

I have turned off [line wrap](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27wrap%27) in **Vim** by adding this in my **vimrc**:

```
set nowrap
```

But, I would like to have line wrap turned on automatically when I am editing `*.tex` files. So, I added this to my vimrc:

```
augroup WrapLineInTeXFile
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType tex set wrap
augroup END
```

This should enable line wrap when the filetype is detected to be TeX. This works as expected for tex files, but if I open a non-tex file in the same Vim session, it has line wrap turned on!

[Enabling and disabling word wrap automatically on different file extensions on Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146410) suggests using BufRead instead. But, even that has the same effect: if I first open a TeX file, followed by a non-TeX file, the non-TeX file has line wrap turned on.

How do I correctly enable line wrapping only for a certain filetype?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `setlocal` for this.  It'll only affect the current buffer.

```
augroup WrapLineInTeXFile
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType tex setlocal wrap
augroup END
```

That'll be applied to every new TeX buffer.

Answer (score 5):

The `'wrap'` option is *local to window*. When you use `:set`, it will also apply to any newly opened windows. You want to use `:setlocal`.

Also, though your `:augroup WrapLineInTeXFile` works, it is cumbersome and doesn't scale to many settings. If you have `:filetype plugin on` in your `~/.vimrc`, you can place filetype-specific settings (like `:setlocal wrap`) in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` (use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/tex.vim`).

Comment: Ingo: Though I don't need it in this case, your suggestion is useful if I keep accumulating settings in my vimrc :-)